# greenfield tag plagiarism

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

The [greenfield](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greenfield) tag has a wiki excerpt right now that's a direct copy and paste from Wikipedia. I would correct it with a citation but even then, it's just a single sentence and feels kind of low quality in that way. I can't queue an edit to simple delete the entire excerpt so I'm asking someone with privileges either do that or at least fix it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I've rolled it back to being empty.

Tag excerpts can't contain any markdown so adding a citation isn't really sensible.